# Background colour change Bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

totally rookie question I know, 
but I am trying to change the background colour in bootstrap

i change using

```
body{background:#fff;}
```

which works, i can see the change at the bottom of the page, 
but the whole page and it's entire width is still white

within my page all I then have is

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
```

i have changed the body of container and row respectively but its not those. also tried changing the colour of .wrap as inpection shows its contained in that too, but nothing changes the full background and Im a little stumped as to what is blocking it. - Ive not written any actual code yet, its just the standard install and a roots theme.

anyone know what is going on here? i know it will be something stupid.

Code is here

```
<div class="wrap" role="document">
<div class="content row">
    <div class="main col-sm-12" role="main">
        <div class="page-header">...</div>
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
            </div><!-- end row -->
        </section>      
    </div><!-- /.main -->
</div><!-- /.content -->
```

none of these have any background colours applied to them.

Comment: You are changing the background to white... no? #fff =white

Comment: `html, body{background:#fff;}` use this.

Comment: no, apologies!  just using that as an example sorry. - i use #ccc i should have said.

Comment: Send us your code, html + css, and <head> so we can help you.

Comment: Ive added the html above. there is no css yet other than i have tried to change body background. - the other styles are whatever is default in bootstrap, would you like me to add them?

Comment: With the information provided I don't see anything wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/GeraldS/F7QvS/

Comment: Ok, try this: <body style="background:#333333;">. That means you type that inline so you can see if your css is applied or not.

Comment: my stylesheet is working fine, as i always check by adding the a universal 1px border. - will try that now and see what happens

Comment: ive applied that. again, it does the same thing, just darkens the bg but i can only see it at the bottom of the page. - whatever elements are in the page at 100% are white and covering the body background. - only problem is, nothing in the css has white applied to it and i am stumped.

Comment: How about html tag, does it have any styles inline or in css? Are there any !important styles? You say nothing has white applied, how about background: none; background-color: none; or opacity: 0; Is there any javascript involved? I am running out of ideas...

Comment: I reinstalled the theme and it worked. it appeared to all be taking on the style of the navbar. so I am wondering if I may have been missing a comma or a closing tag somewhere .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using LESS - if you haven't come across it before it essentially allows you to use variables in CSS. It's very handy.

Anyway, you could always use the customisation options when downloading bootstrap to configure the background colour.

Have a look here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: i will look at that, trouble is it's kind of mixed in with a barebones template - i'm using the roots template.

Comment: No but I'm presuming changing the background colour isn't the only modification the OP will ever want to make...

Comment: this is making me feel extremely dense. it should work without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

With every modern browser you can check easily where the active style comes from.

Here is an example using the Chrome developer tools:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools on stackoverflow]

Select the tag you want to investigate, open the computed style and expand the property you need. You'll see every instance where the property is affected and which are overriden by something else.

IE and Firefox have similar tools.

Also, keep in mind that the order of used Stylesheet matters.

Comment: Hi Gerald, 
yes I know, I'm using chrome dev tools, checked all that, - the body has changed, but all thats sat in

Comment: Hi Gerald, 
yes I know, I'm using chrome dev tools, checked all that, - the body has changed. but you can only see it at the bottom of the site. - can't post a photo at this time, - frustratingly.

Comment: So, check where the color comes from, override it. Without posting actual code nobody here will be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
body {

  background-color: #your color code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the roots theme and bootstrap. added it again, 
added the couple of changes I had made previously, (enqued stylesheet)

then I changed the backkground of the body again. 
now it works.

i havent a clue why it didn't before, I didnt add any colours anywhere else, I had only just started modifying it. - buggy perhaps?

but my answer to this is - maybe I broke my theme inadvertently.